# Do we put the indefinite article before "scales"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, articles, singular-vs-plural, british-english

(In British English)

What do we say?

> I weigh food on **a** scales

or

> I weigh food on scales

And what is the difference between scale and scales?

Comment: This is subtle, but there are two questions here.  One on whether "a scales" is an appropriate combination, and another on whether to use "scale" or "scales".

Answer (score 14):

There are some words in English where a single item uses a plural noun.  Examples are:-

- scales (as you say)
- scissors
- trousers
- pants
- knickers
- tights

Usually these are items where the original object has two or more parts (two pans for traditional balance scales, two blades for scissors, two legs for clothes worn below the waist).  Over time (and in some cases with changes in the items themselves) the plural form has become the standard noun for the single item.

The equipment used for measuring weight may be described as "a scale" or as "scales".  Both are used, although you will see "scales" more often in general use; "a scale" is seen more often when describing scientific or technical equipment.  You cannot say "a scales", in the same way as you cannot say "a dogs", because "scales" and "dogs" are plural, and "a" describes a singular noun.

Comment: And as an owner of sleeves, which for bicycling are actually not attached to a shirt, but are literally two sleeves worn like open ended socks over the arms, I appreciate how the trousers eventually became connected into one wearable item.  Scales having two pans fits with everything else, even if technology eventually made spring scales, and  other kinds of scales that no longer need the other pan.

Answer (score 11):

In British English, although a 'pair (or set) of scales' is very common, we can say 'a scale'. This is a scale that I bought in the UK about 6 months ago from a well-known chain of supermarkets. It cost £8 ($11 US)

[image: picture of a digital scale]

Comment: Also true in my idolect (Philadelphia PA area, USA). "Weigh those grapes on a scale. There's one in the next aisle."

Comment: The modifier "a" follows the count of the noun.  "A scale" is fine" but "a scales" is always wrong.  If you opt to use scale in the plural or singular, just make sure the modifier matches in number.

Answer (score 5):

*Scales* (meaning a balance or weighing machine) is usually plural:

> The scales are in the bathroom.

When we want to refer to a single balance, we can say "a pair of scales", but I think most people would use that only for a traditional balance with two pans.

The Oxford English Dictionary remarks of that meaning of *scales* "(†In 16th cent. rarely construed as singular)."

The GlowBe corpus has a few instances of *a scales* meaning a weighing machine: Britain: 1; Ireland: 3; New Zealand: 1; USA: 4.

It also has a few instances of *the scales is*: Britain: 2 (34 _ the scales are_); US 2 (27 with *are*).

So, while a few people use *scales* as singular, it's quite rare, and the evidence does not show it as any more British than American.

And for your question, *I weigh the food on scales*, or (especially if you use a traditional balance) *on a pair of scales*.

Comment: I would *never* call an electronic weighing machine "a pair of scales". Probably "a scale".

Comment: Yes, since the migration from two-pan balances to spring-loaded single-pan machines, and then to electronic machines, the idea that it's a plural object has pretty much disappeared from my mind. (I'm 53.)

Answer (score 4):

> ### [scales pl (plural only)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scales)
>
> A device for measuring weight.
>
> *The butcher put the sausages **on the scales.***

If you don't mean any scales in particular, no article is needed since it's always plural. I couldn't find any reasonable example when you can say it without the definite article, though.

Comment: *"without the definite article"* - you might use *some* if it doesn't matter which ones, eg "I checked the weight on[/using] some scales"

Answer (score 3):

I would probably avoid both.

I'd probably say "the kitchen scales", or just "the scales"

This works because there is only one such device in the kitchen.  There are times when it is difficult to find an acceptable expression with a word like this that is always plural.

> I went to the shop to buy .....

1. the kitchen scales (no good because they aren't determined)
2. a kitchen scales (no good because we can't use "a" with plural.  However this has some actual use.)
3. a kitchen scale (no good because scales is always plural, but this also has some use)
4. kitchen scales (no good because this sounds like multiple devices, but again, this is seen in the wild)
5. some kitchen scales (possible, but still not perfect)
6. a pair of kitchen scales (only possible if you are refering to the "balance" type)
7. a set of kitchen scales (seems odd for a single item)

As you see there is no perfect solution.  Perhaps this context comes up so rarely that there is no agreed solution.  If pushed I'd probably choose "some scales" as the best option.

Comment: "a kitchen scale (no good because scales is always plural, but this also has some use)" - isn't that a contradiction. If the singular has some use, how can it be always plural? Lexico says "scale" is "usually" plural - not quite the same thing.

Comment: I went to the shop to buy 3, 4 and 5 — all make perfect sense and are very idiomatic

Comment: @rjpond Yes, something of a contradiction.  See other answers.  The fact that this is a word used in the plural  would make 3 unacceptable  for some people, but some other people do use it.  If a learner says "a scale"  there are some people out there who will say they have made a mistake. Likewise with 4 and perhaps 5. I actually think English is deficient in the this, or rather it has boxed itself into a corner.  The always/usually plural term works fine in most contexts  "Put it on the scales"  but not in indeterminate contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I heartily disagree with the answers that cite *scales* as plural only.

See [this google n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bathroom+scale%2Cbathroom+scales&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbathroom%20scale%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbathroom%20scales%3B%2Cc0):
[image: Google n-gram of "bathroom scales" vs "bathroom scale"]

N-grams for "put it on the scale[s]", "get on the scale[s]" have a similar pattern.

Comment: This chart doesn't differentiate between groups of scales, as in "we are having a sale on bathroom scales" which would still be plural even if one referred to any single bathroom scale as a "bathroom scale".  So, the data, while interesting is far from conclusive.

Comment: @EdwinBuck That makes the plural count suspect. But the singular count cannot be confused with the plural ... so your observation makes it even LESS likely that "scales" is always plural, which is what I dispute. I don't assert that scale is always singular, I assert that saying it's never singular is wrong.

Comment: The OP asked about BrE.  According to some sources, "scale" sgl is US (see https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scale partway down the page).  Although NGrams also shows a significant count for "scale" if you select "British English", NGrams' BrE/AmE filters are not especially reliable.  Still - Michael's contribution showed that the singular form does have some currency at least in the UK, and Lexico UK says only that the word is "usually" plural.

Comment: @rjpond Very well. I completely missed the BrE from the original question. Think I should delete this answer?

Comment: @RossPresser No opinion on keeping or deleting the answer, but I'm in full agreement on how you described the impact on the N-gram.